# how to use RVM to a ruby app engine?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, heroku, rvm

i wanna make a simple ruby App Engine in rails just like heroku, i'm dealing with a problem now.

My idea was:

1.use rails to establish the App Engine, use a class 'App' to handle all apps.

2.when a user create an ruby app he should offer it's git path

3.when the user deploys it, my app engine will do these things:

- clone the git to a path in my server (done
- use RVM to designatine the ruby version witch user wanted and make a gemdir for the project (some problems here
- create a nginx conf for the project, then include it and reload nginx (i can do it

Problems in the second step:

codes here:

```
  def start_thin
    Dir.chdir(proj_path) do
      system('rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p352@testname --create')
      system('gem env gemdir')
      success = system ('thin start -s3 --socket ' + self.proj_sock)
      if success
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
```

when the code runs here, the log told me "RVM is not a function...blahblah", i know something about the login-shell and non-login-shell, then i try to fix it via editing .bashrc but same problem occurred.

And if i ignore it, the app can't be deployed, because of a Load Error :

```
myapp.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
```

if i open a terminal in that app directory, i can use thin to start it.

i wanna know how to run cmd just like in a terminal, without all these odd problem?
or how to edit my method to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Under which user are you running your rails app? Also is your rvm installed in a user account or system-wide? Remember you need to have both running under the same user (rails app + rvm).

Comment: first confirm if rvm is properly installed. Try rvm notes for that.Also execute rvm gemset create gemset1 and check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Casper and GhostRider.

The user and rvm settings are correct.

After lots of googles and tests i found it's impossible...
Finally I fixed it by using RVM's ruby api instead of running system command.
Such as :

```
require 'rvm'
env = RVM.current
env.gemset.create('app1')
```